# Why I cannot create a DataFrame whose colum is a list of two floats?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

positions = np.array([[2.2,3.1],
                      [2.3,6.2], 
                      [2.4,9.3]])

df = pd.DataFrame({'pos': positions})
```

It returns the following error

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Comment: You are passing a two-dimensional array to fit in one column, what result did you expect? ;]

Comment: Show the result that you expect to get.

Comment: @MykolaZotko - I expect that after executing `df['pos']`, it returns 3 elements, each of them a list of 2 floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is being interpreted as two columns, use [tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

positions = np.array([[2.2, 3.1],
                      [2.3, 6.2],
                      [2.4, 9.3]])

df = pd.DataFrame({'pos': positions.tolist()})

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          pos
0  [2.2, 3.1]
1  [2.3, 6.2]
2  [2.4, 9.3]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly on the lines of what I am looking for. The only but is that, to access the number `9.3`, I would expect to use only two indexes: the first one indicating the last row and the second one indicating the last element in that row. However, in practice, I need to use three indexes `df.pos[2][0][1]`. Do you know why the index `[0]` is necessary?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, just ran the code that is in the answer and did `df.pos[2][1]` and it works. Perhaps something to do with the version of pandas?

Comment: My bad. I had typed `df.values` instead of `df.pos`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pd.DataFrame(positions)
```

Result:

```
     0    1
0  2.2  3.1
1  2.3  6.2
2  2.4  9.3
```

Hope this helps.